# How to efficiently truncate the text that contain html tags in it when rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example text containing aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<b>a</b>*****. If I use text.slice(0,26) or substring is displaying aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<b>a</ now; which is resulting in a bad rendeing. That is the output I am expecting is aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa**a** not  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<b>a</. Please help me. I am stuck with this from long time. My only requirement is that truncate the html tags that are incomplete at the end and display the other text as properly formatted one. Note: Should not replace all html tags, only tags that are incomplete at the end need to be replaced

Comment: What *exactly* do you want the result to be?

Comment: Your question is too vague.. Kindly format it properly with an example.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: Have you looked at what the [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), and [.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) functions actually do?

Comment: In short: No.  You can't treat HTML as Text as just truncate it in a random/fixed position.  If you have some idea of the content (eg is it just bolds/italics or can there be nested html such as tables) then you could, possibly, build it up until you get to a max length, but nesting will break that considerably.   Either use text-overflow (as comment above) and let the browser **do it for you** or add `white-space:hidden` to your container.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be helpful.

```js
function truncate(str) {
  if ((str === null) || (str === ''))
    return false;
  else
    str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
}
console.log(truncate('aaaaaaaaaa<html>aaaaaaaaaa<b>a</b>'));;
```

Comment: Not all html tags can be replaced